# Override IIS Response Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Since I am hosting multiple websites on the same IIS instance, I defined the HTTP Response Header 'X-Frame-Options: DENY' in the IIS settings to ensure my clients (and their clients) protection against clickjacking.

I am currently working with WebForms on an e-commerce website and I need to remove the 'X-Frame-Options' response header on a specific url (the callback of my payment provider).

I have written an HTTP module (see code below) and registered it in the 'web.config' of my e-commerce website, the code works, but it seems that IIS adds the response headers after the execution of my HttpModule.

```
public class XFrameOptionsControl : IHttpModule
{
  public void Dispose()
  {
  }

  public void Init(HttpApplication application)
  {
    application.PreSendRequestHeaders += new EventHandler(PreSendRequestHeaders);
  }

  private void PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;

    string callbackDocumentName = "callback.html";

    if (callbackDocumentName != null)
    {
      if (!context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(callbackDocumentName.ToLower()))
      {
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Normally, the 'callbackDocumentName' is retrieved from the 'web.config', but I did simplify it for the example. I tried debugging with Visual Studio and the 'context.Response.Headers' contains the following headers, but not the 'X-Frame-Options':

- CacheControl
- Content-Type
- Server
- X-AspNet-Version

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be of help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I have already considered this article before posting on Stackoverflow; sadly, there is not 'ALLOWALL' for the 'X-Frame-Options', so I really need to remove it from the headers, I cannot only modify it

Answer (score 0):

if you want change the response, you need to do it after the response is generated.

currently you did it even before the request is sent to your application

try this

```
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(this.ProcessResponse);
        }

        private void ProcessResponse(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            //do whatever you want to the context
            //context.Response.Headers.Remove
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, it didn't work for me because I am using Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest elsewhere, so PostRequestHandlerExecute got bypassed. I even tried on EndRequest, which is triggered by CompleteRequest, but it seems IIS adds the response headers after all events in the pipeline got executed, so I guess I'm gonna have to control the X-Frame-Options in my code, withtout IIS.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time searching for this, I finally got it, you must use rewrite rules in order to replace your custom headers in certain files and set it in the load or another init method of the page, here is the example of how to bypass the CSP header in all aspx and html files:

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Remove Content-Security-Policy Header" preCondition="IsHtmlOrAspx">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content-Security-Policy" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="IsHtmlOrAspx">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.aspx$|\.html$" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```